# SQL Azure Database DTU Comparison

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have question on DTU and their power in each tier. 
Microsoft has listed DTU for each service tier here :https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

P2 has 250 DTU and S6 has 400. I have a process that run fine in P2, the process is CPU intensive. Is it right to assume the same process will do fine in S6 because it has higher DTU?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process should do fine in S6 given that your application is mostly using CPU resources. The standard tier does not support columnstore indexing and memory-optimized tables so check that you are not using these features. For a finer comparison of the standard tier and the premium tier, you can look to this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits).

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have found is DTU comparison across tiers is not really possible. For example if you take a S4 which is 200 DTU and compare it to the P1 with is 125 DTU, the Standard is an order of magnitude slower than the Premium.